# Perl Dancer2 Authentication Password Management

Tags: perl, authentication, hash, passwords, dancer

So any one who has used perl dancer knows that to authenticate a user on login you can call authenticate_user

```
authenticate_user(
    params->{username}, params->{password}
);
```

This is part of the Auth::Extensible plugin.

To me it looks like it encourages the use of storing passwords in plain text! Sure you can hash the password first then make sure the stored password is the same hash but this seems to be more of a work around and i found isn't guaranteed to work. I have only got this to work using sha1 which shouldn't be used. I want to use Bcrypt but the passphrase simply wont match. Possibly odd characters not matching i'm not sure.

The thing is using the dancer Passphrase plugin i can already validate the username and password without even needing to rely on authenticate_user to verify them. But for the dancer framework to consider the user logged in you still have to call authenticate_user which must be passed the password.

I'm completely stuck. I'm curious how other people have managed to use proper password management in dancer2?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have even skimmed through [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible) documentation.

Comment: I only post on places like this as a last resort after reading all the documentation i can find. If your going to just give a typical rtfm type response at least back it up with some reasoning otherwise "It doesn't look like you have even skimmed through" the question.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the password needs to be stored in plain text? The code you've shown takes the credentials supplied by the user. They are obviously plain text, but they are not stored anywhere, just received over the wire. `authenticate_user` will take care of hashing and comparing under the hood. How it does that is completely transparent. It comes with a bunch of different providers, but you can also roll your own if you need something else.

Comment: To clarify i am using "provider: 'Database'" so i have a db with a users table. The reason why i say it encourages plain text password storage is because authenticate_user will not authenticate unless params->{password} matches exactly whats in the database. It doesn't hash it. 
However - "user_password username => 'jbloggs', new_password => 'secret'" will hash it in sha512 before storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'll echo the "you almost certainly don't need to be using `authenticate_user()`" comments.  The plugin can handle all that for you.

However, "it doesn't hash it" is wrong; here's how it works.  The
`authenticate_user` keyword loops through all auth realms configured, and for
each one, asks that provider's `authenticate_user()` method to see if it accepts
the username and password.  The `Database` provider (and the others) fetch the
record from the DB, and use `$self->match_password()` (which comes from the
[Provider role](https://metacpan.org/source/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Role::Provider)) to validate it; that code checks if the stored password from
the database starts with `{scheme}` and if so, uses
`Crypt::SaltedHash->validate` to validate that the user-supplied password (in
plain text, as it's just come in over the wire) matches the stored, hashed
passsword (`$correct` in the code below is the stored password):

```
if ( $correct =~ /^{.+}/ ) {

    # Looks like a crypted password starting with the scheme, so try to
    # validate it with Crypt::SaltedHash:
    return Crypt::SaltedHash->validate( $correct, $given );
}
```

So, yes, if your stored password in the database is hashed, then it will match
it if the password supplied matches that hash.

For an example of what a stored hashed password should look like, here's
the output of the bundled `generate-crypted-password` utility:

```
[davidp@supernova:~]$ generate-crypted-password 
Enter plain-text password ?> hunter2
Result: {SSHA}z9llSLkkAXENw8FerEchzRxABeuJ6OPs
```

See the [Crypt::SaltedHash doco](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SaltedHash) for details on which algorhythms are
supported by it, and the format it uses (which "comes from RFC-3112 and 
is extended by the use of different digital algorithms").

Do bear in mind that the code behind `authenticate_user` is exactly what's used
under the hood for you.

For an example of just letting the plugin do the work for you, consider:

```
get '/secret' => require_login sub {
    my $user = logged_in_user();
    return "Hi, $user->{username}, let me tell you a secret";
};
```

... that's it.  The `require_login` means that the plugin will check
if the user is logged in, and if not, redirect them to the login page
to log in.  You don't need to call `authenticate_user` yourself, you
don't need to set any session variables or anything.  `logged_in_user()`
will return a hashref of information about the logged in user (and because
the route code has `require_login`, there's guaranteed to be one at this
point, so you don't need to check).

If you need to check they have a suitable role, instead of just that they
are logged in, then look at `require_role` in the documentation instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for [Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible), the description for `authenticate_user()` says:

> Usually you'll want to let the built-in login handling code deal with authenticating users, but in case you need to do it yourself, this keyword accepts a username and password ...

Which strongly implies to me that you shouldn't be calling this function at all unless you're doing something particularly clever.

I haven't used this module myself, but it seems to me that all the hashing and encryption stuff should be handled by one of the [authentication providers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible#AUTHENTICATION-PROVIDERS) and if there's not one that covers the case you use, then you can [write one yourself](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible::Role::Provider).

Whenever I need to store secure passwords for a Dancer app, I reach for [Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase). I wonder if I should consider writing an Auth::Extensible style authentication provider for it.

Comment: Correct the encryption stuff should be handled by the authentication provider. The documentation for Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database says Crypt::SaltedHash is used. However authenticate_user still appears to only match on a plain text password in the db. I have ended up using Dancer2::Plugin::Passphrase to do authentication myself but i'm sure what i am trying to do isn't anything special needing that level of work.

Comment: @jeffez: But why are you calling `authenticate_user()`? For most uses, it's unnecessary.

Comment: My understanding is that authenticate_user() is used for checking the username and password before you add the session variables logging in the user. This was all i needed, but passwords would only match on plain text which isn't supposed to happen by default going by the Auth::Extensible::Provider::Database docs. I ended up writing my own username/password matching but it kind of goes against 'convention over configuration'.

Comment: *My understanding is that authenticate_user() is used for checking the username and password before you add the session variables logging in the user.* Then I can only suggest that you take a closer look at [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Auth::Extensible). In normal use, that is all handled for you and you have no need to call `authenticate_user()` yourself.